# Why language is not regular?

Tags: regular-language, dfa, automaton

1. Show that the language is not regular. L = {a^n b^m : n>m}

Comment: I mean how would I write out the answer or even accomplish it, it's my first experience with this

Answer (score 4):

The [Pumping Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) is exactly what you're looking for.
How to use it? Try looking for some [examples](http://compquiz.blogspot.com/2009/11/pumping-lemma-examples.html).